# Is it possible to compile flex 3 charts in intellij?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, intellij-idea

I'm aware that mx.charts is part of flex builder professional.

I've downloaded the trial version of flex builder professional and added the datavisualization.swc to my intellij Flex_sdk classpath. The IDE is now aware of the classes, but when I come to compile I still get:

> "Type was not found"

Is there a license or something I need to add to the classpath.

Can anyone give a step by step guide to compiling a flex app that uses charts, either in intellij, or from the command line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that just adding all the swc classes from the FB3 lib directory to my existing jdk, based on the Flex SDK installation didn't work. However when I removed the Flex SDK all together and added a new one, with the sdk directory based on that of FB3 it started to work.